# Equation for calculating percentile of data point on normal curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, percentile

I'm taking pre-calculus right now, and I'm trying to make a statistics program, so I want to calculate the percentile of a score on a normal curve without using a "standard normal table." I can calculate the z-score easily and correctly, but the equation printed in my textbook doesn't seem to work.

`y = e^(-x²/2)/√(2π)`

(x is the z-score)

Is this the right equation for calculating the percentile of a score on a normal curve? For a z-score of 2.1, I find the solution to be:

`y=e^(-2.1²/2)/√(2π)`

`=e^(-2.205)/√(2π)`

`=e^(-2.205)/2.507`

`=0.11/2.507`

`=4.398E-2`

On the standard normal table, the answer is clearly 0.9821. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm curious why this question got a down vote.  It shows work and presents a valid question.  Maybe a comment could help us know what kind of questions are encouraged here?

Comment: I was also wondering why I was down voted. I'm not a veteran here, so I'm still getting the hang of things. I apologize if I've breached typical etiquette. Usually the questions I have are already well-answered. I'm just looking for the best (or most common) way of finding which percentile a score on a normal curve lies in. I suspect that the equation in my textbook is for another purpose, but I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is the probability density function (pdf) $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2 \pi}$ of the standard normal distribution. What you appear to want is the cumulative distribution function (cdf) $F(x)$ which gives the probability of observing a value less than $x$ from the standard normal distribution. This is the integral of the density from $-\infty$ to $x$:
$$
F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\;dt
$$
Which unfortunately does not have a simple expression in terms of the elementary functions you will be familiar with (and does at least hint at the need for some familiarity with calculus). There are however approximations, some of which are on the [Wikipedia page for the normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Numerical_approximations_for_the_normal_CDF). The simplest of these is the first:
$$
F(x)\approx \frac{1}{2}\left[1+{\rm{sgn}}(x) \left(1-e^{-2x^2/\pi} \right) \right]
$$where $\rm{sgn}(x)$ denotes the sign of $x$. This has a maximum absolute error of $0.003$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. You are correct in assuming that a lot of the information goes over my head, I see why it's not in my textbook. On the Wikipedia page I looked at Bell's approximation and came up with an answer of `0.9847`, which is pretty close! I'll test it out with a few more examples and see if it stays close enough to be of practical use. Is it possible to calculate the cdf with a calculator/program?

Comment: @user3455858 I would normally use a numerical integral, which is easy to program on the systems I use but calculators vary so much I could not say (other than most of them seem to have a built in function to do this)

Comment: Thank you! I inserted the approximation into my program and it works nicely. My calculator doesn't seem to have a function for it, but it is from the early 90's and I have trouble finding things in the 600 page manual. I think this method will work for now. I'd up-vote you but apparently I don't have enough rep...